# Load external images in JavaFX

Tags: image, javafx, imageview, external

I am trying to load external images using JavaFX, but since using the new raspberry 4, I am unable to load external images, I can however load images internal to the Jar file.
as an example I have attached the code below. this works on my mac and raspberry pi3 but does not work for the raspberry pi 4 running Debian Buster, the only difference between the raspberry pi 4 and the there computers is that the RPI4 is running the latest JavaFX openjdk 14.0.1 and the other computers are running version 1.8.0_20.

on all instances i get a print of true for `System.out.println(file.exists());`
the RPI4 can load images inside the Jar, any help please

Code:

```
package application;
    
import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;


public class Main extends Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            Scene scene = new Scene(setupScene(), 300, 300);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Image Screen");
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        StackPane setupScene() {
            StackPane root = new StackPane();

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
            imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
            imageView.setSmooth(true);

            File file = new File("/home/pi/dscf4452.jpg");
                      
            System.out.println(file.exists()); 
            System.out.println(file); 
            
            Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
//          Image image = new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.jpg").toString());
            
            imageView.setImage(image);

            root.setPrefSize(250, 250);
            imageView.setFitHeight(root.getPrefHeight());
            imageView.setFitWidth(root.getPrefWidth());
            root.getChildren().add(imageView);

            return root;
        }
}
```

Comment: use resource lookup always (except when actually getting a file, f.i. by using fileChooser)

Comment: i would like to give the ability to load own images later without have to go in the jar, can we do this with resource?

Comment: no, a resource path is starting from the application root, not "higher up". hmm .. but then you would need some ux to choose that file, or how would the user interact with your app to choose it? Not familiar with pi (nor linux) - just a wild shot: might it be a missing rights issues?

Comment: the app runs and displays time related info and a background that can be changed by non tech users, this could be a rights issue, but never had this below and running with admin privileges

Comment: okay, then I'm off, sry. you might consider adding tags for your context (didn't check which are available) to attract the attention of rasperry experts :)

Comment: to clarify your query, the app does randomly pick a background when started, and this gives the noobs the ability to load in their customised images in a system folder.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you having trouble loading _resources_? Or _external_ files? Or _both_?

Comment: trouble loading external images.. i am actually able to list the directory content but am not able to display on latest raspberry 4

Comment: What happens if you try using the `Image(InputStream)` constructor (don't forget to close the `InputStream` afterwards)?

Comment: tried this, but does not work on pi4 but works on macOS InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/pi/dscf4452.jpg");  Image image = new Image(inputStream);

Comment: something is weird going on. I just can't figure out why

Comment: Does your `FileInputStream` actually return any bytes? Also, I'm not sure if it's set for synchronous image loading, but you can check the `Image#exception` property.

Comment: As well as @Slaw's suggestions, check `file.canRead()` and `Files.getPosixFilePermissions(file.toPath())`. This seems like it must either be a permissions issue, or something really weird with the JDK access to the filesystem. Maybe also do a quick test and see if you can read a simple text file? (Probably for completeness test your application on your Mac with JDK14, but I don't think that will reveal much.)

Comment: file.canRead() is true

Comment: i get on osx [OWNER_EXECUTE, OTHERS_EXECUTE, GROUP_EXECUTE, OWNER_WRITE, GROUP_READ, OWNER_READ, OTHERS_READ] and on pi [OTHERS_READ , OWNER_WRITE, GROUP_READ, OWNER_READ]

Comment: i also get the size of the inputstream: System.out.println(inputStream.available());

Comment: how can i get Image#exception

Comment: is this because i am compiling using old jdk on osx and running on pi4 with latest jdk

Comment: "how can i get Image#exception " `if (image.isError()) image.getException().printStackTrace();`